# Why can't I convert unicode string to plain python string?

Tags: python, encode, urlencode

```
url = u'/wiki/Category:%E6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A'
```

The decoded string is (through https://www.urldecoder.org/):

```
decoded_url = u'/wiki/Category:打磚塊'
```

In python, I have the following code to do this conversion:

```
decoded_url = url.decode('utf-8')
```

This code doesn't change it at all. I also tried:

```
decoded_url = url.encode('utf-8')
```

The string remains the same. How to convert it to the decoded string I want?

Comment: That's not UTF-8, it's a special URL encoding method.

Comment: `urllib.parse.unquote(u'/wiki/Category:%E6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not `UTF-8 encoding` but `url escaping` or [url quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting)

```
import urllib.parse

print( urllib.parse.unquote( u'/wiki/Category:%E6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A') )
```

Result

```
/wiki/Category:打磚塊
```

---

Python 3.x doc: [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

---

**EDIT:**

`Python 2.7` has it in module `urlparse`

```
 import urlparse

 print( urlparse.unquote(u'/wiki/Category:%E6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A') )
```

---

Python 2.7 doc: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html)

---

**EDIT:**

After testing with `Python 2.7` it needs `encode()` before `unquote()` to work with `str` (plain text) instead of `unicode`

```
#-*- coding:  utf-8 -*-
import urlparse
 
url = u'/wiki/Category:%e6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A'
url = url.encode('utf-8')    # convert `unicode` to `str`
url = urlparse.unquote(url)  # convert `%e6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A` to `打磚塊`

print url
print type(url)
print '打磚塊' in url
```

Result

```
/wiki/Category:打磚塊
<type 'str'>
True
```

---

**BTW:** The same for `Python 3` - it doesn't need `encode()`

```
import urllib.parse
 
url = u'/wiki/Category:%e6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A'
url = urllib.parse.unquote(url)  # convert `%e6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A` to `打磚塊`

print(url)
print(type(url))
print('打磚塊' in url)
```

Result:

```
/wiki/Category:打磚塊
<class 'str'>
True
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7. It doesn't have urllib.parse?

Comment: `python 2.7` has also module `urllib` and `urlparse` and it has quoting functions somewhere in `urlparse`

Comment: I added example for `python 2.7`

Comment: But it gave this "u'/wiki/Category:\xe6\x89\x93\xe7\xa3\x9a\xe5\xa1\x8a'", not the readable characters

Comment: you get correct string but you have to use `print()` to display it correctly. If you don't use `print()` then it uses `repr()` to display `UTF-8` codes instead of `chars` (for debuging)

Comment: Please see the testing on my Mac above. My purpose is to test whether the URL string contains some words, like if '打磚塊' in url:

Comment: you should have `True`  for `if '打磚塊' in urlparse.unquote(...)`

Comment: But one is plain string, and the other is not. No way to compare. That is why i want to convert to plain string first.

Comment: then use `u"'打磚塊"` to compare with unicode from `unqoute` or use `urlparse.unquote(...).encode('utf-8')` to get plain text. OR better use Pyhton 3 because unicode in Python2 is big problem.

Comment: BTW: if you have new information then add it in question - don't add to my answer.

Comment: With unqote and encode, it gives "/wiki/Category:æç£å¡". Please test it.

Comment: It works correctly in `Python 3` - but it after testing it with `Python 2` I found it needs `encode()` before `unquote()`. All because `unicode` in `Python 2` was big mess and it was hell for programmers. I added this to answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's Python 2.7 code that gives you the result you want from the original string in your question:

```
import urlparse

utfStr = u"/wiki/Category:%E6%89%93%E7%A3%9A%E5%A1%8A"
asciiStr = utfStr.encode()
str = urlparse.unquote(asciiStr)
print(str)
```

Result:

```
/wiki/Category:打磚塊
```

It appears that `unquote` does the wrong thing when given a unicode string.  You have to first convert it to single-byte string before `unquote` will do the right thing.

Comment: my original anwer was for `Python 3` because I didn't expect that someone still use `Python 2` :)

Comment: @furas You need to put a 'u' before the string. Mine is a unicode string. In that case, your code give broken characgters in Python 2

Comment: Sorry.  I got the 'u' issue mixed up in my first answer.  Should be what you want now.